# getting an error reading simpleDomObject

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have the following template file, named 'test.html'

```
<div class='title'>TEST</div>
```

And I have the following PHP code:

```
<?
include "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";
$dom = file_get_html( "test.html" );
echo $dom->outertext;
?>
```

So far so good, this displays the file test.html. But when I try to change something I get an error:

```
<?
include "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";
$dom = file_get_html( "test.html" );
$dom->find('.title')->innertext = "changed";
echo $dom->outertext;
?>
```

**Warning**: Attempt to assign property of non-object in **E:\internet\test.php** on line 4. Though I do believe I'm exactly following the manual. What is going wrong here? Obviously $dom->find('.title') didn't return a valid element, but the question is: why? It should find the DIV?

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: tried it with phpQuery, ran into another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522438/phpquery-ignores-part-of-an-imported-file

Comment: update: with the question in the comments solved I switched to phpQuery. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

You obviously missed index for found elements, so there isn't property `find()->innertext`
repaired code here:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";
$dom = file_get_html( "index.html" );
$dom->find('.title',0)->innertext = "changed";
echo $dom->outertext;
```

Second:

I **wouldn't recommend** you to use `Simple Html DOM` library, beacuse it's old and not actual
Take a look at `QueryPath` library, which is doing the same and is in better condition.

http://querypath.org/