# phpQuery ignores part of an imported file

Tags: php, html, parsing, phpquery

the following code:

```
<?
  require_once "phpQuery.php";
  $dom = phpQuery::newDocument( "<head></head><body>this is ignored</body>" );
  echo nl2br( htmlentities( $dom ) );
?>
```

should give this is ignore, but the entire body seems to be ignored.

I stripped down the code to where the problem was still there. I want to read links `($dom->find('a'))` from the body, but found out nothing was found even though there were links in the body.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does phpquery require valid xml bodies? If so, you should wrap your document in a `<html>` tag.

Comment: that did show the body indeed, but it also adds content to the page itself. So it's kind of a brute force solution... For now it works though.

Comment: for other people that might run in this problem: I fixed it by checking if the document war wrapped with <html></html> tags, if not, wrap the document in those tags before passing it to phpQuery: $dom = phpQuery::newDocument( ( strpos( $html, "<html>" ) === false ) ? "<html>$html</html>" : $html );